# 『坊っちゃん』の「親譲り」と「損」の理解のし方

Tags: words, literature

> **親譲り**の無鉄砲で小供の時から**損ばかり**している。

-夏目漱石『[坊っちゃん](https://www.aozora.gr.jp/cards/000148/files/752_14964.html)』より

この句において、

親譲りの意味は[これ](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/33700/meaning/m0u/)によると英語での inherit と理解できるはずです。が、
その辞書の解釈には

> 親から性格・財産などを受け継ぐこと。**また、そのもの。**

「そのもの」を英語での itself などの意味だと理解しても大丈夫ですか。大丈夫であるなら、その(親譲り)例はありますか。

もうひとつの質問は、その「損ばかり」を「いたずらばかり」と理解してもいいですか。

Comment: 財産などを受け継ぐこと: The act of inheriting. そのもの : The inheritance itself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

「そのもの」というのは親から譲り受けた性格や財産など、受け継がれたもの自体を指します。この場合、「無鉄砲」がこれに当たります。

「損をする」というのは、意味合いで言えば英語の Lose、Lose out などに似た言葉です。[大辞林の解説](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E6%90%8D-555748)によると

> そん【損】：
>   利益を失うこと。益のないこと。不利であること。また、そのさま。 ⇔ 得 ・ 益 「千円の－をする」 「口べたで－をしている」 「 －な役回り」

「無鉄砲で損ばかりしていた」というのは、要は、あまりにも無鉄砲だったせいで、例えば問題ごとを起こし親に叱られたり、事故に遭ったりなど、いろいろときつい目にあわされ続けたといった感じですかね。

Comment: "あまりにも無鉄砲だったせいで"の"あまりにも"は英語では"too", "extremely"などと翻訳するんですか。

Comment: 英訳で言えば、"Due to his overly reckless nature (...)"や"He was so rash that (...)"などが近いと思います